# Is there another purpose for ether besides buying gas?

Tags: ether, blocks

Were ether coins invented only in order to buy gas? Or can I trade it too (like in bitcoin) ?

thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use ether like a currency, just like Bitcoin. Ethereum allows users to send ether from their own address to another address. At the present time, one ether has a market price of just over 500 USD.